# Can't increment ID in database using PHP

Tags: php, mariadb

I'm a student and I've hit a wall...

what I got:

```
function new_id($table, $id_column_name)
{
require_once ("config.php");
$db=mysqli_connect($host,$usernamesql,$passwordsql,$db_name)
           or die ("could not connect");

$query="SELECT MAX($id_column_name) 
            AS max FROM $table";

$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
$result2=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$idnew=$result2['max']+1;
return $idnew;
}
//this function is located inside libs/lib.php
```

The following code is located inside /signup.php

```
require ("libs/config.php");
//DB connection stuff

require ("libs/lib.php");
//function above

id_user = 'id'; 
id_student = 'id_student';
//these vars represent column names in users/students tables
//tried `id`, 'id', "id" quote variations, nothing seems to work 

$db=mysqli_connect($host,$usernamesql,$passwordsql,$db_name) 
           or die ("could not connect");
$idnew = new_id($tbl_users, $id_user);
$query="INSERT INTO $tbl_users (id, username, passwd, sex, married, lasttname, firstname, email, datereg, extension, phone) 
        VALUES ('$idnew', '$username', '$passwd', '$sex', '$married', '$lastname', '$first', '$email','$currentDate', '$image_type', '$phone')";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);

$idnew = new_id($tbl_student, $id_student);
$query="INSERT INTO $tbl_student (id_student, lastname, firstname)
        VALUES ('$idnew', '$lastname', '$firstname')";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
```

So as you can see I try to add to the users table and students table with the added bonus of incrementing the id for both tables rows.

It adds to tbl_users just fine but it doesn't increment the id. I didn't set it to unique so I ended up with a couple rows with id=1. It doesn't add anything to tbl_student though and I can't figure out why...

It's worth mentioning that I manually added one row to both tables in foresight that the function would take the MAX id of 1 and +1 to increment the id to 2.

Finally I guess there's something wrong with my function there but I can't for the life of me figure out what...

Comment: Why are you not using auto incrementing columns?

Comment: I don't see anywhere you assign the value for `$tbl_users` and `$tbl_student`, are you sure you have the right table name?

Comment: That's assigned in config.php. (edit: it does INSERT into DB like I said, wouldn't be able to if those vars wouldn't exist somewhere...just doesn't increment the id, also it doesn't save anything into tbl_student)

Comment: wait...i'm confused...the function is inside libs/lib.php; the db name,tables,passwd,etc are inside libs/config.php. My 'adding stuff to db code' is inside a signup.php file in the root directory, so /signup.php. I see here I require(); before I do new_id($table, $id);

Comment: @olayemii It's an assignment...I can't. Need to do it with PHP.

Comment: @ErrorCheck try var_dump($result2); in the max id getter function, so you can see what is happening

Comment: You can set that id column as "Auto Increment" in your database

Comment: Study both `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Put `require ("config.php");` instead of `require_once ("config.php");`

It doesn't like `require_once` inside a function I see.
For some reason this worked for me. It even adds to the tbl_student which it didn't before at all, nevermind incrementing any id.

My guess is(haven't researched) that inside a function you can have loops(if, for, while) and it forces you to `require` so that you can use the required file inside those loops.